# C++ : Calling a child method from parent instantiation

Tags: c++, inheritance

In my code, I have these classes implemented :

```
class A
{
  public:
    virtual int fun() { return 0; }
}

class B : public A
{
  public:
    virtual int fun() { return 1; }
}
```

And these functions :

```
void operation(A a)
{
  printf("%d\n",a.fun());
}

int main()
{
  B b;
  operation(b);
  return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the class B inherits of A, and implements the virtual inherited method `fun()`. The main class calls a function that takes a A in parameters and calls the `fun()` method, with a B object in argument.

At the execution, I expect the string `"1"` to be printed, but it's `"0"` that is (even if it's a B object that is passed to `operation()`).

I need to do this because I have several B classes (B1, B2, etc...) and I want the function `operation()` to be generic.
I don't need the implementation of `operation()` in the class A, but if I declare `operation()` pure virtual, the compilation fails at `operation()` saying that I can't instantiate A (it's quite expected).

I've found many topic talking about parent/child methods calls and inheritance, but none of them talked about this problem precisely.

Can someone help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: Careful: For default construction of an object, you mustn't use parentheses. `B b()` does not call `B`'s default c'tor, but declares a function `b` that takes no arguments and returns an object of class `B`.

Comment: It's just a mistake I made when I wrote this simplified code sample

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to pass the object by reference or pass a pointer

```
void operation(A& a)
```

Because you're passing by value, the derived object gets sliced - a new object of type `A` is created in the scope of the function.

Comment: That seems obvious now that you say it. Works fine now, thanks a lot ^^ !